# Realtime Database not updating // Firebase Data not Updating in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is the problem:
[image: This is the problem]

These are the rules I set in Firebase:
[image: These are the rules I set in Firebase]

The Current users in Firebase:
[image: The Current usersin Firebase]

When I make a new user, It should be updated in Firebase Realtime DB.
But in this case, this does not help.
I even changed the read, write rules to true, it doesn't help & keeps showing null.

**//CODE BELOW//**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
    supportActionBar?.hide()

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    edtName =findViewById(R.id.edt_name)
    edtEmail =findViewById(R.id.edt_email)
    edtPassword =findViewById(R.id.edt_password)
    btnSignUp =findViewById(R.id.btn_signup)

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener{
        val name = edtName.text.toString()
        val email = edtEmail.text.toString()
        val password = edtPassword.text.toString()

        signUp(name, email,password)

    }
}
private fun signUp(name:String, email: String,password: String){
    //logic for signup

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                //going homE
                addUserToDatabase(name, email, mAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)

                val intent= Intent(this@SignUp, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUp, "Some Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }

}
private fun addUserToDatabase(name:String, email:String, uid:String){
    mDbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

    mDbRef.child("user").child(uid).setValue(User(name, email, uid))

}

}
```

//User Class Code//

```
package com.example.mychat

class User {
   var name : String? = null
   var email : String? = null
   var uid : String? = null

   constructor(){}

   constructor(name:String?, email:String?, uid:String?){
     this.name= name
     this.email=email
     this.uid=uid
   }


 }
```

Comment: Where is the "User" class?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#public-taskvoid-setvalue-object-value
"In addition, you can set instances of your own class into this location, provided they satisfy the following constraints:
The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a Custom Object to Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874535/writing-a-custom-object-to-firebase-database)

Comment: @SujalKumar Updated the User Class Code.

Comment: I am not much familiar to Kotlin but as mentioned by @TylerQI, you need to make public getters and setters for each property.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(User(name, email, uid))` operation to see if something's wrong?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the .addOnCompleteListener shown below in the answer, but that dosen't seem to help. I am neither getting toast message of "User Added" nor an "Error message"

Comment: If you're getting neither a completion nor an error listener, did you download your `google-services.json` before you first accessed the database in the console by any chance? In that case, the file might not contain the database reference that the SDK needs. To fix this, download a new `google-service.json` from your project and use that in your app, or specify the database URL in your code in `mDbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("URL here").getReference()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting neither a completion nor an error listener, did you download your `google-services.json` before you first accessed the database in the console by any chance? In that case, the file might not contain the database reference that the SDK needs. To fix this, download a new `google-service.json` from your project and use that in your app, or specify the database URL in your code in `mDbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("URL here").getReference().`

**This Solution by @Frank van Puffelen worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, all you need to do is, goto firebase console -> Real time database -> rules (from the top toolbar in the same page) and change the rules into:

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
}
```

and you are all set, it worked for me!